# Regex replace - match and empty all lines not containing a specific character

Tags: regex, string, notepad2

I can not use grep. In fact, I am in Notepad2. When I want to remove lines containing character "c", I am using the replace dialog (Ctrl+H):

```
Search string: ".*c.*"
Replace with: "" (nothing)
```

After that, I sort the lines and I get rid of the empty lines.

But now I need to empty all lines that actually *do not* contain character "c". Is it possible to do it in Notepad2?

If I can do it in Notepad2, then I can do it using JavaScript's String replace too, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could anchor your pattern and use a negated character class.

```
Find: ^[^c]*$
```

Explanation:

```
^          # the beginning of the string
 [^c]*     # any character except: 'c' (0 or more times)
$          # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```